# SQL left join with grouped table

Tags: sql, oracle

received some great help on a previous question on this site.
Im new to sql and trying to get my head around this.
From table Tourenstatistik I will get unique rows of data with a date & id.
I am then looking at another table Vtsbreak and summing up the duration for each id on separate dates as there can be more than one entry for the same id on the same date.
I then want to return that sum in a column called duration for the unique id & its date.

I also need to specify the start and finish dates for my query.

I have found something similar but I cant get it to work
coming up with error ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended.

Any suggestions please?

```
Select
    Tourenstatistik.DATUM "Date",
    Tourenstatistik.MITARBEITER "ID", 
    VtsPause.Duration
From
Tourenstatistik
Where Tourenstatistik.DATUM >= TO_DATE('2017/05/15', 'yyyy/mm/dd') AND Tourenstatistik.DATUM <= TO_DATE('2017/05/16','yyyy/mm/dd') 
Left Join 
(Select
    Vtsbreak.MITARBEITER_NR "ID",
   sum(Vtsbreak.DAUER) "Duration",
   Vtsbreak.datum "Date"
From
Vtsbreak 
Where DATUM >= TO_DATE('2017/04/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd') AND DATUM <= TO_DATE('2017/05/27','yyyy/mm/dd') 
group by MITARBEITER_NR, datum;) as VtsPause 
On (Tourenstatistik.MITARBEITER = VtsPause.MITARBEITER_NR and Tourenstatistik.DATUM = VtsPause.DATUM) 
order by Tourenstatistik.DATUM, Tourenstatistik.MITARBEITER
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are giving the columns aliases in the subquery.  You then need to use those aliases.  Also, the `WHERE` clause is misplaced.

```
Select ts.DATUM as "Date", ts.MITARBEITER as "ID", b."Duration"
From Tourenstatistik ts Left Join 
     (Select b.MITARBEITER_NR, b.datum, sum(b.DAUER) as "Duration"
      From Vtsbreak b
      Where b.DATUM >= DATE '2017-04-01' AND
            b.DATUM <= DATE '2017-05-27'
      group by MITARBEITER_NR, datum
     ) b 
     On ts.MITARBEITER = b.MITARBEITER_NR and ts.DATUM = b.DATUM 
Where ts.DATUM >= DATE '2017-05-15' and
      ts.DATUM <= DATE '2017-05-16'
order by ts.DATUM, ts.MITARBEITER;
```

You have numerous things wrong with the query, plus a few suggestions:

- You had a semicolon in the middle of the query.
- You gave columns aliases in the subquery, and then used the original column names.
- You had a misplaced `WHERE` clause.

Recommendations:

- Use table abbreviations as table aliases, so the query is easier to write and to read.
- Use the `date` keyword for defining date literals.

Comment: I get error 936 missing expression. If I remove the , after as Duration I now get 904 error b.duration invalid identifier

Comment: @SThomas . . . The double quotes are a bad idea, but I left them in anyway.  If you have them, you need to use them.

Comment: Great that worked a treat. thanks for breaking it down as to where I was going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking the "as" off of "as VtsPause".  Also, get rid of the semicolon after "datum;".  I'd also not give column aliases in double quotes on the inline query, especially since you refer to the actual column name in your ON clause.

Also, your first WHERE clause is out of place.

Perhaps this will work:

```
Select
    Tourenstatistik.DATUM 
    Tourenstatistik.MITARBEITER, 
    VtsPause.Duration
From
Tourenstatistik
Left Join 
(Select
    Vtsbreak.MITARBEITER_NR,
   sum(Vtsbreak.DAUER) duration,
   Vtsbreak.datum
From
Vtsbreak 
Where DATUM >= TO_DATE('2017/04/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd') 
  AND DATUM <= TO_DATE('2017/05/27','yyyy/mm/dd') 
group by MITARBEITER_NR, datum) VtsPause 
On (Tourenstatistik.MITARBEITER = VtsPause.MITARBEITER_NR 
   and Tourenstatistik.DATUM = VtsPause.DATUM) 
Where Tourenstatistik.DATUM >= TO_DATE('2017/05/15', 'yyyy/mm/dd') 
  AND Tourenstatistik.DATUM <= TO_DATE('2017/05/16','yyyy/mm/dd') 
order by Tourenstatistik.DATUM, Tourenstatistik.MITARBEITER
```